# Passing data from child to parent in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I am trying to implement a very simple functionality that would update my state based on the value passed into a function. The function is declared in my parent component, is passed to my child component via props and it is being called on a child component.

I keep getting this error on the console:
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.

Here is my code:
Parent component

```
import React, {Component } from "react";
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import Content from './Content';

class Tabs extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            message:'Select a name from the tabs menu'

        };
        this.handleName = this.handleName.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount () {
        if ('pluginLoaded' in window) {
            (window).pluginLoaded('tabs', function (port: any, context: any) {
                // Future work should interact with the message channel here
            });
        }
    }

    handleName(value){
        if (value === 'Vanessa'){
            console.log(`${value} in da house `)
            this.setState({
                message: 'Vanessa means "butterfly"'
            })
        }


    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="Tabs">
                <Sidebar 
                    handleName = {this.handleName}
                />
                <Content
                    message = {this.state.message}
                />


            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Tabs;
```

Child component

```
import React from 'react';

const Sidebar = (props) =>{
    let Vanessa= 'Vanessa';
    let Paola = 'Paola';

    return(
        <div className="Sidebar">
            <h1>Tabs</h1>
            <ul>
                <li><a onClick={props.handleName(Vanessa)}>Vanessa</a></li>
                <li><a onClick={props.handleName(Paola)}>Paola</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}


export default Sidebar;
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of:

`<li><a onClick={props.handleName(Vanessa)}>Vanessa</a></li>`

try:

`<li><a onClick={() => props.handleName(Vanessa)}>Vanessa</a></li>`

Comment: Worked perfectly. Do you mind explaining why this works or why it was not working before. i just want to understand why the need of a anonymous function here. I would appreciate your explanation, but if no time for it no biggie!

Comment: @vanegeek In your version you were executing the function rather than passing a function as a prop. Parenthesizes cause a function to execute therefore you create an anonymous function to pass to onClick prop. Another vay could be using [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for example, `onClick={props.handleName.bind(this, Vanessa)}` this would also bind the event object to the function

Comment: @Chanzi Please add more context to your answer to make it clear for the asker.